# editBox.Text to int - my program crash when I insert something else than number

Tags: c#, .net

I have simple calculator in C#.NET WF. But when I insert to my editBox something else than number, my program crash. How should I do to avoid this crash?

```
private void doMath()
{
    int n1 = Int32.Parse(editBox1.Text);
    int n2 = Int32.Parse(editBox2.Text);

    String o = operation.Text;

    switch(o)
    {
        case "+": result.Text = (n1 + n2).ToString();
            break;
        case "-": result.Text = (n1 - n2).ToString();
            break;
        case "*": result.Text = (n1 * n2).ToString();
            break;
        case "/": result.Text = (n1 / n2).ToString();
            break;
        case "%": result.Text = (n1 % n2).ToString();
            break;
        default: result.Text = "No operator selected.";
            break;
    }
}//end doMath

private void editBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doMath();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int32.Parse` relies on the fact that you have an int to begin with. So trying to parse `123` will work, but trying to parse `123e` will throw an exception.

Using `Int32.TryParse` will ask for an output `int` but will take care of the ugly exceptions if you pass something that isn't an int, and the return of the operation will tell you if it was successful or not. 
If it was, you got your value in the out parameter, if not, it'll have the default value for the type (0 in our case).

```
int i;
bool b1 = Int32.TryParse("123", out i);  // i = 123, b = true;
bool b2 = Int32.TryParse("123e", out i); // i = 0, b = false;
i = Int32.Parse("123"); // i = 123
i = Int32.Parse("123e"); // you got an ugly exception
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int n1 = 0;
Int32.TryParse(editBox1.Text,out n1);
int n2 = 0;
Int32.TryParse(editBox2.Text,out n2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can catch this exception:

```
try{

    int n1 = Int32.Parse(editBox1.Text);
    int n2 = Int32.Parse(editBox2.Text);
}catch(FormatException e){
    result.Text = e.toString() + "\nEnter numerical value only";
}
```

Comment: But don't use exception handling if you can use `int.TryParse`. Invalid user input is not an exceptional case.

Comment: Sure thing. It's just an alternative where for some reason you can't use `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers here are correct, but I'd add a little more description:

```
int firstNum;
Var isFirstNumeric = Int32.TryParse(editBox1.Text, out firstNum);
int secondNum;
Var isSecondNumeric = Int32.TryParse(editBox2.Text, out secondNum);
```

Now you could use `firstNum` and `secondNum` as you use n1 and n2 in your original example, *but* you should test for validity first:

```
if(!isFirstNumeric)
{ 
    ShowErrorMsg("The first value is not a valid number!");
}
else if(!isSecondNumeric)
{ 
    ShowErrorMsg("The second value is not a valid number!");
}
else
{
    // We know both numbers are valid.
    // Place your switch here and calculate as before...
}
```